# SQL Developer doesn't connect using Hostname of my machine

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm not able to connect to local oracle database from SQL Developer when I'm giving my computer hostname for "Hostname" field in SQL Developer connection.

Database and SQL Developer are running on the same machine.
SQL Developer was able to connect when hostname are replaced with following:

localhost   --localhost as hostname is working

127.0.0.1   --This is working as well

192.168.0.5 --Static IP Configured for machine is working

10.10.10.10 --Loopback configured for machine is working

**Attached files showing following info:**

**"Config files details"** : hosts, tnsnames.ora, listener.ora, sqlnet.ora

**"SQL Developer and Network adapter details"** : Network adapters used, Screen shots showing the SQL Developer connection details

My Machine is a standalone home PC, So, it doesn't have any domain name associated with it.
It is configured both loopback and Static-IP and hosts file reflects them appropriately.
My Home Wifi-Router is configured to assign Static-IP to my machine based on MAC-Address.

Resolving this is required because, I have used my computer hostname instead of IP-Address as source connection for some other application (Same machine), which i don't want to modify, as the static IP-Adress might need to be modified later and that would require to go to the other application again and again.

I've tried to delete and create the listener afresh, that didn't work !! Not sure, what's wrong with this Hostname.

Thanks,

Durga.

[SQL Developer and Network adapter details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1yqm.png)

[Config files details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv8og.png)

Edit: Also, weirdly enough, SQLPlus connects to the host when i give the password directly in connection string. However, it says TNS doesn't know of the service when i don't give password as part of connection string. (Attached the screen shot)

[Screenshot showing the behaviour of SQLPlus With/Without password in connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0WEI.png)

Comment: Did you enter your computer name along with the IP address into the HOSTS file? On Windows 7, it is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` directory (you'll find an example of how to do it in the file itself).

Comment: I did that now, restarted the machine to try. but that's not working as well. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Right; sorry it didn't help.

Comment: did you try in the listener.ora change host = prafessional to host = 0.0.0.0 which makes the listener bind to all IP addresses ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. I had re-installed my OS as i've brought new SSD and thought to have fresh installation. i wouldn't be able to verify this issue now. Thanks for answering my question. Have a great day !!